# Why list is not getting passed to IActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Why is the list `newsletterSubComponents` not getting passed to `IActionResult`. Can anyone help please. I know there is one option `BindProperty` but i can not use it since this list is coming from a partial view. I can only modify the list which is inside the model which is being passed to the partial_view.

**List in model**

```
List<NewsletterSubComponents> newsletterSubComponents = {get; set;}
```

**Partial view**

```
  @{

    Model.newsletterSubComponents.Add(new Models.NewsletterSubComponents() { NewPlantArticleId = 0 });
    Model.newsletterSubComponents.Add(new Models.NewsletterSubComponents() { NewPlantArticleId = 2 });

}

@for (var i = 0; i < Model.newsletterSubComponents.Count; ++i)
{
    <select class="form-control Shoplist News-plant-select_1 mt-2" data-search="true" asp-for="@Model.newsletterSubComponents[i].NewPlantArticleId">
        <option value="0">Bitte auswählen</option>
    </select>
}
```

**Controller**

```
 public IActionResult OnPostUpdateComponent(NewsletterComponents component, int? newsId, int? shortArticleId,
        List<NewsletterSubComponents> newsletterSubComponents, int? newPlant1, int? newPlant2, int? newPlant3)
    {
        var dbComponent = _context.NewsletterComponents.Find(component.NewsletterComponentId);
        if (dbComponent == null)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
        dbComponent.NewsId = newsId;
        dbComponent.ShortArticleId = shortArticleId;
        dbComponent.newsletterSubComponents = component.newsletterSubComponents;
        dbComponent.NewsletterMoreLink = component.NewsletterMoreLink;
        dbComponent.CustomLinkText = component.CustomLinkText;
        dbComponent.NewsleterComponentText = component.NewsleterComponentText;
        dbComponent.NewsletterComponentHeadline = component.NewsletterComponentHeadline;
        dbComponent.EditedBy = User.Identity.Name;
        dbComponent.EditedDate = DateTime.Now;
        _context.Update(dbComponent);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        UpdateNewsletterHtml((int)dbComponent.BelongsToNewsletterId);

        return RedirectToPage(new { id = dbComponent.BelongsToNewsletterId });
    }
```

`newsletterSubComponents` parameter is empty when i debug!

Comment: Im not understanding your issue, what is the problem? in the controller the newsletterSubComponents is null?

Comment: @nalnpir yea exactly , the `newsletterSubComponents` is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have update the method to pass the list via javascript, you can refer to the following example.

In partial view, I inject the pagemodel and smimulate some data.

```
@model projectname.Pages.IndexModel
@{

Model.newsletterSubComponents.Add(new Models.NewsletterSubComponents() { NewPlantArticleId = 0 });
Model.newsletterSubComponents.Add(new Models.NewsletterSubComponents() { NewPlantArticleId = 2 });

}

<form>
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.newsletterSubComponents.Count; ++i)
    {
         <select class="form-control Shoplist News-plant-select_1 mt-2" data-search="true" onchange="changeVal(event)" asp-for="@Model.newsletterSubComponents[i].NewPlantArticleId">
            <option value="0">Bitte auswählen</option>
        </select>
    }
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <button type="button" onclick="send()">btn</button>
</form>
```

Use javascript to pass this list.

```
@section Scripts{
<script>
    var SubComponents = [];
    var s = '@Model.newsletterSubComponents.Count()'
    for (var i = 0; i < s; i++) {
        SubComponents[i] = { "NewPlantArticleId": $("#newsletterSubComponents_" + i + "__NewPlantArticleId").val() }
    }
     function changeVal(e) {
        let nid = e.target.id
        let k = nid.replace(/[^0-9]/ig,"")
        SubComponents[k]={ "NewPlantArticleId": $("#newsletterSubComponents_" + k + "__NewPlantArticleId").val() }
    }
    function send() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/?handler=UpdateComponent',
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
            },
            data: {
                newsletterSubComponents: SubComponents
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data)
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('ee')
            }
        })
    }
</script>
}
```

Then, access the backend.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your time, one thing though, the list is being populated via javascript not asp-items="components". Can I pass a list to the controller only?

Comment: Yes, but I want to know how do you send the list to controller? Because it may be affected by model mapping.

Comment: ok i will look into this, maybe my approach is not good. but i was trying to pass the list, just like we pass string or int to controller.

Comment: Do you use ajax?

Comment: @AmirDora. you can refer to it. Note: the ajax need to add `RequestVerificationToken`.

Comment: @AmirDora. can you accept it as an answer? Or do you have any other issues? please let me know.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. sorry for late response. I have accepted your answer :)